# Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions on web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis

i recently started to learn asp.net in order to create some web application.
took me some time but eventually i managed to make the IIS work according to some guide on the internet.
after entering the IIS manager i opened a new application and tried to use the browse option on it and i received this error massage.

[image]

the app runs without any problem on visual studio.
i believe the problem is in the configuration file but still dont know how to fix it.
thx in advance.

Comment: its not the IIS configuration file, but the web.config - and its better to write in text the error message. How ever the error is the same as the other question.

Comment: The message says that the web.config did not have permissions for write. So you find the user under the witch pool is running and give that permission to web.config.